# Css button pressing effect

Tags: html, css, animation, button, input

I have a button with a  box-shadow that makes it look like it's floating, and I would like to make a pressing effect when I click on it:

Code(CSS):

```
#startBtn
{
    font-family: OpenSans;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #00FF7C;
    border: 1px solid #00FF7C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #00823F;
}
```

Code(HTML):

```
<input type="button" id="startBtn" value="Let's begin">
```

Screenshot:

[image: Button]

Comment: Just look at this example: [https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJKQEYQ8AXA8](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJKQEYQ8AXA8).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `:active` pseudo class and change the box-shadow vertical offset value. Adjust the `top` value for the activated element with respect to the relatively positioned input with absolute parent.

```css
.button {
  position: absolute;
}
#startBtn {
  font-family: OpenSans;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #00FF7C;
  border: 1px solid #00FF7C;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #00823F;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
#startBtn:active {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #00823F;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <input type="button" id="startBtn" value="Let's begin">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'd also like the button to be moving downwards.

Comment: You can change the height value to make it look downwards.

Comment: Take a look to the button on the top right of this website: http://www.suomi24.fi

Comment: Code updated with transition.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 6):

IF the buttoms have a fixed height (as it looks) I would wrap the buttom into a div with that height and set the button to position absolute to create the right effect (moving it down) with:

```
#startBtn:active {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #00823F;
    bottom:-4px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/r39vae5b/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `hover` property:

```css
#startBtn:hover { 
  /* your css code here */ 
}
```

Another option is to use button generators like [buttongarage.in](http://buttongarage.in) to generate your code for the button and the hover effect.

Comment: buttongarage.in appears to be broken now (2019-02)